# Getting a string between two substrings in PHP?

Tags: php, string, substring, strpos, referrer

I need to get the username from a referring URL (only if the referrer starts with "/members/" after the hostname.

What I have currently isn't working, but how can this be modified to get a user's name from a URL?

```
// example URL
// http://domain.com/members/john-doe/something
// note that domain.com or protocol can change

$string = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$start = '/members/';
$end = '/';

$startpos = strpos($string, $start) + strlen($start);

if (strpos($string, $start) !== false) {
    $endpos = strpos($string, $end, $startpos);

   if (strpos($string, $end, $startpos) !== false) {
        echo substr($string, $startpos, $endpos - $startpos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) to break up the URL and then match it with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match):

```
if (preg_match('~^/members/([^/]+)~', parse_url($string, PHP_URL_PATH), $matches)) {
    // path starts with "/members/"
    // $matches[1] is the user name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this -

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/members/john-doe/something';
$urlParts = explode('/', $url); // get all parts of te url
if('members' == $urlParts[3]) { // test and display
    echo $urlParts[4];
}
```

Here is an [example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/bvp8-4hmp).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo) for this:

```
$pathDir = pathinfo(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
$directories = explode('/', $pathDir);

if(array_search('members', $directories) !== false) {
    // perform your magic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I came up with:

```
$string = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$start = '/members/';
$end = '/';

$startpos = strpos($string, $start);

if ($startpos !== false) {
    $endpos = strpos($string, $end, ($startpos += strlen($start)) + 1);

   if ($endpos !== false) {
        echo substr($string, $startpos, $endpos - $startpos );
    }
}
```

It is based on the OP's code, but I have implemented some fixes.

On the 3rd and 4th `strpos`, the OP forgot to set the `$startpos + 1`, so it doesn't match the `/` on the substring `/member/`, but on the next char.

Any doubts, I'm free to answer them.